# Make Android Application that Can't Closed

Tags: java, android, webview

So currently I'm building my exam webview app for Android with Android Studio and I'm writing it on Java. I wonder if I can make the app cannot be closed by user without restarting the phone, so my student can't cheat.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Why don't you track the closing of application and design it that way, that after minimizing  or closing the exam will be over for the user?

Comment: `Make Android Application that Can't Closed` this just sounds like a virus :)

Comment: If you are going to be deploying your app on hardware that you or test administrators control, you will have some options related to this, such as kiosk mode. If your app is designed to be used on the test-taker's own hardware... then a_local_nobody's comment is the core of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For obvious security reasons, you can't force Android to keep your activity alive and ignore all user attempts to leave it/destroy it.
This might be possible on modified versions of Android (if your school provided tablets to student for example), but not on anyone's phone or tablet.

As said @Steyrix, the best way is to track closing of leaving the app, which should be easy to implement using the appropriate events.
So to answer your question, you can't prevent them from cheating, but you can tell if they did.

Comment: You could in case of leaving your application maybe show a notification to return immediately within X seconds or the exam is over? If an unintended click could leave the application already

Comment: The OnPause() event launches when user leaves the activity without destroying it, so I think this is the appropriate event in this situation. Then just add your code in it

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this by overriding those methods  in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ///put nothing 
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```